# Remove duplicate list from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all let me acknowledge that this question has been asked before, but the answers either seem outdated or unsatisfactory. The question is given a list of unsorted list, how can we remove duplicates in the most efficient and elegant manner? (i.e. using the shortest syntax vs. the fastest computational time)

Example:

Given `[[1,2,3],[],[2,-2],[3,2,1]]`, we want `[[1,2,3],[],[2,-2]]`. Note that whether `[1,2,3]` or `[3,2,1]` doesn't matter.

Comment: what do you mean by "duplicate"? with same elements or with same elements & length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> li=[[1,2,3],[],[2,-2],[3,2,1]]
>>> {frozenset(e) for e in li}
{frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({2, -2}), frozenset()}
>>> [list(x) for x in {frozenset(e) for e in li}]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, -2], []]
```

The key is to use `frozenset` since a set is not hashable. Note the order may change with this method.

If you want to maintain the same order, you can do:

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> [e for e in li if frozenset(e) not in seen and not seen.add(frozenset(e))]
[[1, 2, 3], [], [2, -2]]
```

If there is a possibility of repeated elements *within* the sublists, you can sort the sublists and use a representation of that:

```
li=[[1,2,3],[],[2,-2],[3,2,1],[1,1,2,2,3],[1,2,1,2,3]]
seen=set()
nli=[]
for e in li:
    re=repr(sorted(e))
    if re not in seen:
        seen.add(re)
        nli.append(e)

>>> nli
[[1, 2, 3], [], [2, -2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]]
```

(Note: You can use `tuple` instead or `repr` if desired. Either produces a hashable immutable result)

Comment: This does not work when there is a repeated element in one of the sub-lists.  I.e. `[[1,1,2,3], [1,2,3]]`

Comment: @ james If set-equality is being used, and lists `[1,2,3]` and `[3,2,1]` are considered equivalent, then why would there ever be duplicated elements?

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: His point was valid. It is because for the sub elements `set([1,1,1,2,3])==set([1,2,3])` but those might be considered unique. The OP did not specify, but valid observation.

Comment: I guess you could also do `tuple(sorted(e))` for your third example.

Comment: As opposed to `repr`? That works too... Just needs to be immutable to be hashable